# Access GE plugin api from WebWorker

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

I have a web application which heavily uses the Google Earth Plugin API.

There are times when my UI becomes unresponsive when a lot of subsequent calls are made to the plugin.

I'm already using [executeBatch](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#ab26414915202d39cad12bcd5bd99e739) and I've tried splitting up the work into multiple deferred `setTimeout(fn, 0)` batches so as not to block too long.

I was wondering if it would somehow be possible to get a reference to the `GEPlugin` instance from inside a WebWorker. This would let me do all the heavy lifting there so my UI thread doesn't get bogged down.